# Using the WHERE equivalent with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have recently started playing with LINQ.  However, I have hit a wall in relation to the WHERE equivalent (and how you use it).  I have looked online, but can't quite get it.

I am trying to create a search function based on two textboxes, but could do with a pointer as to how to add the WHERE part to my LINQ query as highlighted below:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ZZ_Testbed.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListView Name="dataGrid1" Margin="0,78,0,0">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding contact_id}"
                                Header="Contact ID" />
                    <GridViewColumn 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding org_name}"
                                Header="Company" />
                    <GridViewColumn 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding adr_one_postalcode}"
                                Header="Post code" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button x:Name="btnRun" Content="Run" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" Click="btnRun_Click"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtCompany" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="199,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="308"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtPostcode" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="199,44,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="308"/>
        <Label Content="Company" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="139,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60"/>
        <Label Content="Postcode" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="139,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;


namespace ZZ_Testbed
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private ObservableCollection<r2_search_general_source> egwObservable;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnRun_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TestFunction();
        }

        private void TestFunction()
        {
            egwEntities db = new egwEntities();

            //WHERE I NEED HELP - Adding WHERE equivalent using txtCompany & txtPostcode
            var returnData = (from p in db.r2_search_general_source
                              select p).ToList();


            egwObservable = new ObservableCollection<r2_search_general_source>(returnData);
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = egwObservable;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What does `txtCompany & txtPostcode` mean?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to filter against, but where goes before select. So "from blah in whatever where blah.name = txtName.Text select blah" is what you want.

Comment: Why are you posting your xaml? Is it somehow relevant to your question?

Comment: Thanks guys - I should have figured that one out (a little too tired).

Comment: Check this out: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Thanks Dialecticus - that will come in handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
var returnData = (from p in db.r2_search_general_source
                  where p.SomeColumn == txtCompany.Text 
                              select p).ToList();
```

**UPDATE:**

```
 var returnData = (from p in db.r2_search_general_source select p);

if(!String.ISNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCompany.Text)) 
{ 

returnData = returnData.Where(x=>x.SomeColumn == txtCompany.Text);
}

if(!String.ISNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPostcode.Text))
{
returnData = returnData.Where(x=>x.SomeColumn == txtPostcode.Text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you - But what if one or both of the fields are populated.  Also, if I want to have a listbox allowing the user to use the text as "Start of value", "Part of value", "Entire value" etc.  To do that I would need to create some sort of variable and implement that to the LINQ string.

Comment: yes you have to use switch statement or if else code

Comment: you can also use `or` in where clause

Comment: Ehsan - really sorry - but could you give me an example?

Comment: ``var returnData = (from p in db.r2_search_general_source
                  where p.SomeColumn == txtCompany.Text || p.SomeColumn == txtPostCode.Text
                              select p).ToList();``

Comment: No, I've understood that part - it's the using of a IF / SELECT statement within the string that has me stumped.

Comment: you have to write like ``if(!String.ISNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCompany.Text)) {   }``

Comment: Thank you - I think that will get me close, but how do I insert it into the string (it doesn't seem to like it)?

Comment: Thank you so much Ehsan (and everyone else who helped) - genuinely appreciated - have a great weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Use where clause like normal csharp code

```
var returnData = (from p in db.r2_search_general_source
where id==2 && name=='nam'
    select p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx) `where` clause and `&&` operators.

```
var returnData = (from p in db.r2_search_general_source
                  where p.org_name == txtCompany.Text &&
                        p.adr_one_postalcode == txtPostcode.Text
                  select p).ToList();
```